# App is "Developer Rejected",but previously downloaded from the App Store, will it work?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I'am wondering what will happen if my App which was previously available on the AppStore and has been downloaded by some users, but now `I REJECT MY APP` and put it down from the AppStore.

My Question is, Will the previous users who have the app on their devices will work or not???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every user who downloaded the app will be able to keep using it.

There is no way to pull it from there devices.